# Let's make the Tour bilingual

Tags: discussion

There was repeated request for making our [Tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour) bilingual for newcomers to better make clear that we accept questions and answers written in both, German and English. This would be similar to the [French Language Tour](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour).

Here is the right place to vote for this proposal, and to discuss details on how we want it to become.

Answer (score 8):

> **Preface:** This proposal is not meant to discuss the wording of the English original. It is only about offering a German translation in the Tour. Whenever the English original text is changed, a new translation should follow.

Parts of the welcome text of the Tour (but not all of it) can be edited. I propose it be translated into German in a second paragraph so that it will appear like this:

> **German Language Stack Exchange** is a bilingual question and answer site for speakers of all levels who want to share and increase their knowledge of the German language. It's built and run by you as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the German language.
>
> **Deutsche Sprache Stack Exchange** ist eine zweisprachige Seite mit Fragen und Antworten für alle Leute, die ihre Kenntnisse über die deutsche Sprache teilen und erweitern möchten. Diese Seite wird von euch allen als Teil des [Stack-Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/)-Netzwerks für Frage-und-Antwort-Seiten gestaltet. Mit deiner Hilfe möchten wir eine umfassende Sammlung aus detaillierten Fragen und Antworten rund um die deutsche Sprache aufbauen.

To further demonstrate that questions in German are welcome, I suggest the following question to serve as an example in our Tour:

- [Gibt es ein Eigenschaftswort für den Zustand, wenn man keinen Durst hat?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/518/gibt-es-ein-eigenschaftswort-f%c3%bcr-den-zustand-wenn-man-keinen-durst-hat)?

Comment: Suggestion: *aufbauen → erschaffen*

Comment: Either the full tour, or not at all. I don't like the solution on French.

Comment: @Em1: you shoud downvote this propsal then. In case you want to elaborate this further consider to add another answer here. This would also to give people the opportunity to vote on it.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you said that only parts can be edited. That means that StackExchange does not support what I would consider the best solution. That would leave me with the suggestion "don't translate". Is that true?

Comment: Only the parts mentioned here, incl. the example question, can be edited. All else has to wait until we may (or may not) have a German interface.